# Spark/Scala load Oracle Table to Hive

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, hive

I am loading few Oracle tables to Hive, it seems to be working but 2 tables are getting error - `IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Decimal precision 136 exceeds max precision 38`
I checked Oracle table and there is no column with Decimal (136) precision, in the source.

Here is the Spark/Scala code in `spark-shell`:

```
val df_oracle = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:SID").option("user",userName).option("password",passWord).option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").option("dbtable", inputTable).load()

  df_oracle.repartition(10).write.format("orc").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(outputTable)
```

Here is the complete error message -

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Decimal precision 136 exceeds max precision 38
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal.set(Decimal.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal$.apply(Decimal.scala:434)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3$$anonfun$9.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3$$anonfun$9.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$nullSafeConvert(JdbcUtils.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:147)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/10/28 07:56:58 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 36.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
17/10/28 07:56:58 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 36.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 36.0 (TID 201, alphd1dx009.dlx.idc.ge.com, executor 1): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Decimal precision 136 exceeds max precision 38
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal.set(Decimal.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal$.apply(Decimal.scala:434)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3$$anonfun$9.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3$$anonfun$9.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$nullSafeConvert(JdbcUtils.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:147)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1928)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1941)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1961)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeAndRead(DataSource.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:404)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:358)
    at $line34.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:41)
    at $line34.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:28)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at $line34.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:28)
    at $line34.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:54)
    at $line34.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:56)
    at $line34.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:58)
    at $line34.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:60)
    at $line34.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:62)
    at $line34.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:64)
    at $line34.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:66)
    at $line34.$read.<init>(<console>:68)
    at $line34.$read$.<init>(<console>:72)
    at $line34.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line34.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line34.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line34.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:415)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:923)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:751)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Decimal precision 136 exceeds max precision 38
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal.set(Decimal.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal$.apply(Decimal.scala:434)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3$$anonfun$9.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3$$anonfun$9.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$nullSafeConvert(JdbcUtils.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$3.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:147)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please let me know what am i missing.

Thanks

`Spark version 2.1.1.2.6.2.0-205`

Comment: Which version of spark  is being used?

Comment: can you post an output of `desc table_name;` command, executed in Oracle's `sqlplus` (for the "problematic" table)?

Comment: `Spark version 2.1.1.2.6.2.0-205`

Comment: It seems to be a bug in spark 2.1.0 which seems to be fixed in spark 2.3. This link may be helpful https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20427

Comment: Thanks N3WOS. its clear that the issue is fixed in 2.3+. The option i have is to either request upgrade of Spark on cluster or do it individual columns and skip the one that is causing issue. I checked the table definition, it is all "Numbers" in Oracle. So it must be in the data that has higher precision which Spark 2.1 cannot handle. Is there a way to find that column/data value so i can either skip that till i get to upgrade Spark.

Comment: Did you mean  to load the table without that column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Workaround 1:**

Create a view in your Oracle DB:

```
create or replace view schema_name.v_table_name
as
select
  cast(number_col1_name as number(20, 6)) as number_col1_name,   /* problematic column */
  col2,
  col3,
  ...
from table_name;
```

and use that view instead of table_name

**Workaround 2:** do the same on the Spark side on the fly:

```
val query = """
(
select
  cast(number_col1_name as number(20, 6)) as number_col1_name,
  col2,
  col3,
  ...
from table_name
) v_table_name
"""

val df_oracle = spark.read
                     .format("jdbc")
                     .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:SID")
                     .option("user",userName)
                     .option("password",passWord)
                     .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
                     .option("dbtable", query)
                     .load()
```

Comment: Thanks MaxU, I like workaround 2 better. It needs some development but i can apply that as generic to other tables having similar issue. Thanks !

Comment: I tested and it seems workarounds would not work exactly for my case. Since its a data issue and one of the Number column in Oracle have some huge value like `999000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` i may have to do decode on the lines that you have mentioned, instead of cast.

Comment: Good answer, just would note that with Oracle you don't use "AS" to alias your SELECT.
So, `(SELECT * FROM table_name) v_table_name` works

Comment: @kfkhalili, thank you for your comment! Are you sure Oracle don't understand "AS"  in `(SELECT * FROM table_name) AS v_table_name`? I can't check it now...

Comment: @MaxU I just used your answer and had to remove the AS used for aliasing the table. Using AS in the column casting and rename both work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'customSchema' as here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20427?focusedCommentId=16942090&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16942090

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to assign custom schema to convert Decimal types to Double during JDBC read.

This answer was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59760349/10412648