# SPARK read.jdbc & custom schema

Tags: apache-spark

With spark.read.format ... once can add the custom schema non-programmatically, like so:

```
val df = sqlContext
.read()
.format("jdbc")
.option("url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true")
.option("user", "root")
.option("password", "password")
.option("dbtable", sql)
.schema(customSchema)
.load();
```

However, using spark.read.jdbc, I cannot seem to do the same or find the syntax to do the same as for the above. What am i missing or has this changed in SPARK 2.x? I read this in the manual: ***... Spark automatically reads the schema from the database table and maps its types back to Spark SQL types. ...***  Presumably what I am trying to do is no longer possible as in the above example.

```
val dataframe_mysql = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "(select k, v from sample) e ", connectionProperties)
```

I ended up trying this:

```
val dataframe_mysql = spark.read.schema(openPositionsSchema).jdbc(jdbcUrl, "(select k, v from sample) e ", connectionProperties)
```

and got this:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: User specified schema not supported with `jdbc`;
```

Seems a retrograde step in a certain way.

Comment: In spark 2 you can pass schema as spark.read.format().schema .. However, spark.read.jdbc returns dataset. You can specify schema to DataFrameReader not to Dataset. A weird solution can be ..
 RDD<Row> rdd = sparkSession.read().jdbc("","", null).rdd();
sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd, schema);

Comment: It returns dataset only.I tried in Java though. you can also use createDataSet function and provide appropriate encoder

Comment: I am using scala and get in this case dataframe_mysql: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [k: int, v: int]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> . What am i missing or has this changed in SPARK 2.x?

You don't miss anything. Modifying schema on read with JDBC sources was never supported. The input is already typed so there there is no place for `schema`.

If the types are not satisfying, just `cast` the results to the desired types.

Answer (score 6):

I do not agree with the answer.

You can supply custom schema using your method or by setting properties:

```
 connectionProperties.put("customSchema", schemachanges);
```

Where schema changes in format "field Name" "New data type", ... :

```
 "key String, value DECIMAL(20, 0)"
```

If key was an number in original table, it will generate an SQL query like "key::character varying, value::numeric(20, 0)"

It is better than a cast, because cast is a mapping operation executed after it selected in original type, custom schema is not.

I had a case, when spark can not select NaN from postgres Numeric, because it maps numerics into java BigDecimal which does not allow NaN, so spark job failed every time when reading those values. Cast produced the same result. However after changing a scheme to either String or Double, it was able to read it properly.

Spark documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Comment: I seem to have read something to that effect later on in the Databricks docs.

Comment: In my case, I just put the schema to the connection properties, which are provided to jdbc call. It worked, on spark 2.3.*, 2.4.*. Did not tested on different versions. It is possible that just **schema()** method is not suitable for the jdbc case.

Comment: The versions may be the issue.

Comment: Tested on 2.2.1, works as well. This question is old, but if you still interested in specific version I can check. I hope all 2.* has support of custom schema via properties parameter.

Comment: I upvoted you, so we will leave it at that. I will try this weekend.

Comment: I agree. I tested on spark 3.1 and can provide custom schema via `.option("customSchema", myschema)` where `myschema` is a string of valid column sql type mappings. The [Data Source Options in the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#data-source-option) are clear. I just find it a bit unfortunate that the API is different than dataframe reader API.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Custom schema and put in the properties parameters. You can read more at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

**Create a variable:**
c_schema = 'id_type INT'

**Properties conf:**
config = {"user":"xxx", 
          "password": "yyy",
          "driver":"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
          "customSchema":c_schema}

**Read the table and create the DF:**
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url,table='table_name',properties=config)

You must use the same column name and it's going to change only the column 
you put inside the customized schema.

Comment: this was awesome for me, thanks

Comment: @Hugo Pitta what if column name has multiple words like " START DATE"?